# How to apply gradient for text in all browser in CSS3

Tags: css

How to apply gradient for text in all browser in CSS3, I tried:

```
b {
   text-style:gradient;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help. Regarding browser support - Firefox, Chrome and Safari support the unofficial -webkit-background-clip: text (only with prefix). https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-background-clip

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text Gradient</h1>
```